# Searching through C# code to find the Database queries/stored procedures called?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, datatable

I'm trying to backtrace from some C# code that generates a data report in EXcel. It is first called in an ASPX webpage. Here's some of the code:

```
 dtClientSideData = SessionReport.SelectClientIncidenceReport(
                    sSurveyID != "-1" ? sSurveyID : null,
                    sSupplierID != "-1" ? sSupplierID : null,
                    ddlLinkType.SelectedValue != "-1" ? ddlLinkType.SelectedValue : null,
                    ddlTargetType.SelectedValue != "-1" ? ddlTargetType.SelectedValue : null
                    );
```

So dtClientSideData is a DataTable, as shown here:

```
 DataTable  dtClientSideData;
```

Somewhere in the class , it calls a class called SessionReport, and that one directly uses SQL stuff. I'm saying that because it has these imports:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

And in there I see this code:

```
StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure();
sp.ConnectionType = Connections.ConnectionStringType.IncidenceReport;
sp.ProcedureName = "prc_SelectSurveyIncidenceReport";
sp.Parameters = lstParameters.ToArray();
```

As I was typing this I believe I figured it out :p ,  so I'll need to just follow the `sp` here, correct?  My end goal is to reproduce the code into [SSRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services)  .

Comment: ApexSQL Clean can do this sort of thing - sometimes. It depends on it recognizing strings like `prc_SelectSurveyIncidenceReport` as stored procedures or other SQL components.

Comment: Just search the source code for the prefix "Prc_" or "sp_". Recommend you check in SQL files with your code that way you could search in TFS or etc.